# Geany unnecessarily truncates active filename in titlebar

Tags: text-editor, tabs, geany

In my quest for a relatively fat-free editor that still autoloads last session and has syntax highlighting, I became dependent on Geany, customizing it, installed some plugins etc.

Is there a way to have the titlebar print the full name of the file when there's ample space for it, not eating the inner portion with a "..." string instead?  Or customize to shorten anything else but the filename?

I tend to work on lots of files with the same prefix and suffix, differing with only a timestamp or other fields in between.
This makes it hard to distinguish with the glance of an eye which file I'm currently on when switching between tabs.  Already checked the Geany docs online &feature request, so I figured my host OS forum was the next best thing.
[image: Notice 3 rightmost tabs]

Comment: Your best bet would be to join their mailing list and raise your problem, which would probably mean - patch and rebuilding from source, which is not hard, but there would be plugins also to be build and their various dependencies. IMHO, besides that it's great editor for Linux, Geany lacks some common feature customisation (by the fact that it's Scintilla based editor) not mentioning obscure "Tagmanager" handler for identifiers and function prototypes, hard-coded in the source.

Answer (score 1):

There are several alternatives to viewing the full filename for open documents in Geany.

- You can hover your mouse cursor over the tab, and it will display a hint
  that contains the full path and filename.

[image]

- Right-clicking on any tab will generate a list of all open documents, showing the full filename.

[image]

- Finally you can also use the Documents tab in the sidebar and expand
  the panel width to match the length of the longest filenames.

[image]

Comment: All of those are true.  The answer may lie in modifying the Geany code, or making an option for it that doesn't exist yet.